# Sending data to php database

Tags: php, database

So,  I have the following php to submit data (names) to database:

```
<?php   
if(!empty($_POST)){
    global $wpdb;
    $table = 'names';
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    $post_id = 123;
    $parent_id = 0; 
    date_default_timezone_set('Canada/Mountain');
    $date = date('m/d/Y h:i:s a', time());      
    $data = array(
        'post_id' => $post_id,
        'parent_id' => $parent_comment_id,
        'author_id' => $current_user,
        'date' => $date,
        'name_content' => $_POST['name']

    );      
    $wpdb->insert($table, $data);       
} else {
?>      
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" value=""/>
    <input type="submit">               
</form>
<?php } ?>
```

However, it is not sending any data and I am not sure where the error is.

What am I missing with the function?

Thanks!

Comment: this is not your complete script, you leaving the essential part out where the error probably lies

Comment: Guessing here, but I don't think $POST will ever be completely empty... you can add a `var_dump($_POST);` to the top of the function to see it. I think you need (!empty($_POST['name'])) and you probably want to wrap it in a trim to be safe.

Comment: I am thinking it is because I am using `$wpdb ->insert` when the db table is custom called `names". But this is all I have so far. I am going to try not to use `$wpdb`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably you missed connection to DB. Something like

```
$dbh=mysql_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PAS) or die("Connection error");
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed the connection to the DB and the tag `action` in the form that allows you to specify the Php page that will handle the request.